# How to map selected genes to Metabolic pathway Maps

Tags: r, rna-seq, pathway, proteomics, kegg

I have a selected Arabidopsis Genome Initiative (AGI) list for RNA seq and proteomics data, how can I map them to metabolic pathway maps to vilualize(e.g. TCA cycle / FA / Photosynthesis) in KEGG or AraCyc or any freely available pathway maps?

Could someone share an example if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KEGG has a webtool for this, [KEGG Mapper](https://www.genome.jp/kegg/tool/map_pathway2.html).

You can just copy-paste your gene ids in there and see how your pathways are colored.

Comment: Thank you Benn :)